# Mat table copys all rows instead of creating a row

Tags: angular

I created a table with a add row button to get a dynamic table. The problem is everytime i click on the button, it just clones the whole entrys. For ex the user have 2 entrys in the table, i click on the button, then my table have 4 entrys instead of 3.

my table:

```html
<div id="education">
                <h4> Ausbildungen </h4>
                <mat-divider> </mat-divider>
                  <table #educationTable mat-table [dataSource]="educationdataSource">
                   
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="education">
                      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Art.</th>
                      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        <ng-container *ngIf="educationDataLoaded">
                            <mat-form-field *ngFor="let ed of educationType">
                                <mat-select [value]="ed.ausbildungsart.bezeichnung">
                                    <mat-option *ngFor="let education of allEducationTypes" [value]="education.bezeichnung">
                                        {{education.bezeichnung}}
                                    </mat-option>
                                </mat-select>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </ng-container>
                      </td>
                    </ng-container>
                  
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="educationkind">
                      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Abschluss</th>
                      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        <ng-container *ngIf="educationDataLoaded">
                            <mat-form-field *ngFor="let ed of educationType">
                                <mat-select [value]="ed['abschlußNavigation'].bezeichnung">
                                    <mat-option *ngFor="let educationTitle of allEducationsTitleType" [value]="educationTitle.bezeichnung">
                                        {{educationTitle.bezeichnung}}
                                    </mat-option>
                                </mat-select>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </ng-container>
                      </td>
                    </ng-container>
                  
                   
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="deleteButton">
                      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Löschen</th>
                      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        <ng-container *ngFor="let ed of educationType">
                        <mat-icon color="warn" (click)="deleteEducation()"> delete </mat-icon> 
                        </ng-container>
                      </td>
                    </ng-container>
                  
                    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="educationdisplayedColumns"></tr>
                    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: educationdisplayedColumns; "></tr>
                    <tr *ngFor="let field of edfieldArray; let i = index"> </tr>
                  </table>
                  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="addEducation()">Neu</button>
        </div>
```

My declaration and my functions:

```html
@ViewChild('educationTable') table: MatTable<any>;
educationdisplayedColumns: string [] = ['education', 'educationkind', 'deleteButton'];
ausbildung: Ausbildung[] = [ {bezeichnung: '', abschluss: ''}];
educationdataSource = this.ausbildung;
public edfieldArray: Array<any> = [];
public edAttribute: any = {};

addEducation() {
      this.educationdataSource.push(this.edAttribute)
      this.edAttribute = {};
      this.table.renderRows();
      
  }
  deleteEducation(){
    this.educationdataSource.pop();
    this.table.renderRows();
  }
```

```html
//My subscriptions
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      const id = params['id'];
      this.aService
      .getEducation(id)
      .subscribe(data => { 
        this.educationType = data;
        this.aService.getEducation(id).toPromise().then(result =>{
          this.educationDataLoaded = true;
          console.log(this.educationType);
        })
      })})
this.aService
        .getAllEducations()
        .subscribe(data => { this.allEducationTypes = data;  })
//Ausbildungsabschlüsse
this.aService
        .getEducationTitles()
        .subscribe(data => { this.allEducationsTitleType = data; })
```

Here are my subscriptions for the existing values of the users and values which are general and can be selected then(new selected or change the old value).

```html
//Gets specific user values
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      const id = params['id'];
      this.aService
      .getEducation(id)
      .subscribe(data => { 
        this.educationType = data;
        this.aService.getEducation(id).toPromise().then(result =>{
          this.educationDataLoaded = true;
          console.log(this.educationType);
        })
      })})
    //Gets general options for the first column
    this.aService
        .getAllEducations()
        .subscribe(data => { this.allEducationTypes = data;  })
    //Gets general options for the second column
    this.aService
        .getEducationTitles()
        .subscribe(data => { this.allEducationsTitleType = data; })
```

Comment: I tried to replicate your issue and I only get 1 row as expected when trying to add. Is there more code that manipulates your data source?

Comment: What? How is this possible? I checked my code twice and there is only the dataSource i already showed. The informations for the table comes from  a database but i dont think that this will be the problem

Comment: I used the exact code you posted (minus the inputs that I commented) and when I press on the new button, it only adds a single row. That's why I suspected there is more code in your component, that you did not include here, where you might make changes to the data source that lead to the problem you described.

Comment: It seems like he dont insert a new array. Instead of that he clones the listed selects and clones them into one new row, not into mulltiples.